# ComboBox _Click and _Change events triggering on ListFillRange edit? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, events, combobox

Using Excel 2010 here. Starting with a blank sheet, I create an ActiveX combo box.

1) Open the properties window and set:

```
ListFillRange = "A1:A3"
```

2) Manually populate each cell in range A1:A3 with the words "one", "two" and "three", respectively (these strings are arbitrary).

3) Click the combo box drop-down arrow to check that the values appear in the list.

4) Enable Design Mode and double-click the combo box to open the VBA editor, then paste the following code (which assumes the combo box name is is "ComboBox1"):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_change()
    MsgBox "Change event"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_click()
    MsgBox "Click event"
End Sub
```

5) Return to the sheet containing the combo box and disable Design Mode.

6) Click the combo box drop button and select the top item ("one") from the list. Immediately after you release the mouse button you should get two MsgBox windows, one for the _click event and another for the _change event, as instructed by the above Subs.

7) With "one" still selected, double-click in any of the cells in ListFillRange (so, for example, cell "A2")

**Result:** Step 7 triggers both the _click and _change events! This happens whenever a value in the ListFillRange range is edited **AND** the string in the combo box exactly matches at least one of the values in ListFillRange.

Any idea why this could be? Is it a bug? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I don't use ListFillRange for ActiveX controls. You should probably avoid using those. If the data is static then try populating it using AddItem through code.